# How to create a VirtualHost for direct IP access?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

My goal is to block HTTP and HTTPS traffic when the server is accessed directly using an IP address and force SSL for a specific site.

However, I am recieving a CloudFlare 525 SSL handshake failed at `https://example.com`.

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect 403 /
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        Redirect 403 /
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
        RedirectPermanent / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/example.com/.ssl/example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/example.com/.ssl/example.com.key
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

VirtualHost configuration

```
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 10.128.0.2 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost 10.128.0.2 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost examplecom (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:1)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 10.128.0.2 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:6)
         port 443 namevhost 10.128.0.2 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:6)
         port 443 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf:8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate self-signed certificate for my IP address to fix it.

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect 403 /
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        Redirect 403 /

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/self-signed.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the vhost that implements https for the IP address, just add `require all denied` instead of the redirect. I'm afraid there is nothing you can do about the certificate error (other than get a certificate valid for the IP address itself) as the SSL connection is established before Apache can do anything with the request.

Comment: This still did not work. Got an Error 525 SSL Handshake.

Comment: That is a cloudflare error not an Apache one. I suggest investigating the reasons that error occurs. You could be talking SSL to the HTTP vhost, which will never work no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

With Apache 2.4, the first vhost will be main host which located by IP, no need "ServerName"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin YourEmail
    DocumentRoot /home/apache/www
    <Directory /home/apache/www/>
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
Include /path/to/vhosts/*.conf
```

Comment: I took out the ServerName but this made no change. I also updated the post to where I am right now.

Comment: My config should put before "Include *.conf"